# Dynamics CRM 2011, changed domain and ADFS without being able to log in

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Recently we acquired a company which had a server which hosted an instance of Dynamics CRM 2011 (Rollup 16) and authenticated via ADFS. Unable to create a trust or even log into CRM with an account from the previous domain we proceeded to remove it from the previous domain, add it to our own, and configure it to authenticate against our ADFS server.

What we have now is a CRM which no one can log into:

```
No Microsoft Dynamics CRM user exists with the specified domain name and user ID
```

I do have the deployment administrator role as well as SA access into the SQL server. Is there a way of resetting the CRM administrator account or changing the domain and groups via SQL or another route? Much appreciation for any ideas or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imported the organization and mapped the users. Pretty simple, but not so obvious for a first time CRM installation. Thanks.